# I'm trying to apply the do while loop in my c program login but i dont get it

Tags: c

kindly please help me with my problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int samplepre ()
{
    do {

    char username[3]; // users's input username
    char password[3]; //user's input password
    char choice; // Main menu choice
    char x; // option try again
    char string;
    int i; // for for loop : index

    printf ("\t************\n");
    printf ("\t*Login Menu*\n");
    printf ("\t************\n");

    printf ("Enter your username:"); // The user is ask to input its username
    scanf  ("%s",username);
    printf ("Enter password:"); // The user is ask to input its password
    scanf  ("%s",password);

    if (strcmp(username,"admin") == 0 && strcmp(password,"vdedote") == 0)
    {  // if the condition is true the set of codes will execute
       system ("cls");
       printf ("****************\n");
       printf ("*WELCOME ADMIN!*\n");
       printf ("****************\n");
       system ("PAUSE");
       //printf ("\n");
       printf ("What may I be of service sir?\n");
       printf ("************\n");
       printf ("*MAIN MENU:*\n");
       printf ("************\n");
       //printf ("\n");          
       printf ("[A] Remove Vowels\n"); // The user will be asked of his own choice
       printf ("[B] Remove Entered Character\n");
       printf ("[C] Arithmetic\n");
       printf ("Select your choice:");
       scanf  ("%s",choice);

   }
    else 
    {     // if the user inputs wrong data
         // x = option try again
     printf ("****************\n");
     printf ("*ACCESS DENIED!*\n");
     printf ("****************\n");
     printf ("Would you like to try again <Y/N>");
     scanf  ("%s",x);
    }
    while (strcmp(username,"admin") == 1 && strcmp(password,"vdedote") == 1);
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? please be morew specific.

Comment: it expected a 'while' at the end of the input

Comment: Update your question describing where exactly you have difficulties.

Comment: how can i make it not equal ?

Comment: @iharob i want my program to do a do while loop , 
for example if the user entered the wrong username and password, i want the program to ask it all over again until it types the correct username and password.

Comment: The program will most likely crash as it combines `scanf` with an char array of size **3**.  Plus there is no check if the strings are null-terminated before they are send to strcmp.

Comment: please fix your indentation.

Comment: There are to many problems in there, any way you should check scanf for errors. [Try This](http://ideone.com/phRJwF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your question,

- After you corrected the syntactical errors (braces)
- After you have made the indentation look better
- After you have understood the idea of strcmp
- After you have understood that doing it this way is VERY dangerous

then and only then:

should you end the do .. while .. loop with a conditional statement where it is checked IF the user is NOT the admin, then you repeat!

```
    while (strcmp(username,"admin") != 0 && strcmp(password,"vdedote") != 0);
```

so the loop knows it needs to repeat because it is not the admin with the right password login in!

Answer (score 2):

1. You are missing a `}` before the `while`.
2. You need to move username and password out of your loop.
3. You shouldn't use `scanf` http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html
4. You are not allocating enough space for your `username` and `password`

Maybe you should read a tutorial about proper reading first?
The answer to this question looks pretty nice:
[how to read string entered by user in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c)

Comment: i want my program to do a do while loop , for example if the user entered the wrong username and password, i want the program to ask it all over again until it types the correct username and password.

Comment: @vdedote Actually it is pretty clear what you are trying to do. You just made so many errors ... Your idea is correct in most part but the realization is lacking correctness...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace `}` just before the `while`.

Once you've fixed this syntax error, be sure to understand that `strcmp` returns zero *if* the strings are equal.

Comment: i want my program to do a do while loop , for example if the user entered the wrong username and password, i want the program to ask it all over again until it types the correct username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not closing the do !!

```
do{.......} 
while(...);
```

Comment: i want my program to do a do while loop , for example if the user entered the wrong username and password, i want the program to ask it all over again until it types the correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings are equal.

> ```
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `strcmp()` and `strncmp()` functions return an integer less than,
>        equal to, or greater than zero if `s1` (or the first `n` bytes thereof)
>        is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than
>        `s2`.

Comment: it expected a 'while' at the end of the input

Comment: and how will the do while loop works in c program

Comment: The indentation of your code is bad, it's confusing and one needs to count braces in order to tell whether or not they are correct.

Comment: i want my program to do a do while loop , for example if the user entered the wrong username and password, i want the program to ask it all over again until it types the correct username and password.

Comment: The first `strcmp` is correct. Only the second one (in the loop) should use `!=0` instead of `=1`